# Does process.kill() terminate the WaitForExit() (with no time limit)

Tags: c#, process

I have a process that runs in the background and has `WaitForExit()`, since the duration may vary and I need to wait till it finishes. On occasions, I need to end it before it completes and I trigger `.Kill()` command via a class event. The `.HasExited` property changes to true but the code never gets passed the `WaitForExit()` line.

```
public class MyProcess: Process
{
    private bool exited;

    public MyProcess()
    {
            ...
    }




    public void Start(args...)
    {

            try
            {
                base.StartInfo.FileName = ...
                base.StartInfo.Arguments = ...
                base.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                base.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                base.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                base.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                base.Exited += new EventHandler(MyProcessCompleted);
                base.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(outputReceived);
                base.Start();
                this.exited = false;
                base.BeginOutputReadLine();

                    while (!this.exited)
                    {
                      if ()
                        {
                       ...
                        }
                       else
                       {

                    base.WaitForExit(); ---- after the process is killed, it never gets past this line.

                       }

                    ...                    
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ...                
             }
        }


    private void MyProcessCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        exited = true;

        ...  
    }


    private void outputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
           ...
     }


  //Subscription to cancel event
    public void ProcessCanceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        if (!exited)
        {
            base.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

\

UPDATE:

My process launches a java based file transfer client and performs a transfer. The process shows up in the task manager and `Kill()` does not end it. Since I don't really care about ending the process but rather need my program to go to the next "task", I added `Close()` right after `Kill()`, which releases the `WaitForExit` and lets my code "move on". Terminating the process early will be a rare occurance in my app, but I still need it to work, so this implementation will have to do.

}

Answer (score 11):

`WaitForExit` is a direct call to the OS to wait for the process handle to become signaled. When a process terminates, `WaitForExit` *will* complete. `Kill` is a direct call to `TerminateProcess` which is a kill with no questions asked. If used correctly `WaitForExit` will return after `Kill` has completed.

So there is some other bug in your code. Create a simpler repro and you will see the issue disappear. The bug is hidden in the complexity of your code.

Or, `WaitForExit` did return but you did not notice. Or, `Kill` was never executed or failed. Again, simplifying the code will reveal the issue. Can you bring it down to a 5 line repro? I doubt you can, but I will look again if you do.

Try this:

```
Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); p.Kill(); });
p.WaitForExit();
```

Update:

In the comments you specified that killing ping does work, but killing your special process doesn't. The cause for this usually is non-cancellable IO. The Windows kernel keeps processes around until all IO is done. The good news is that the process will die eventually and no code will run after `Kill` has returned. The bad news is that resource cleanup is not fully completed.

You now need to ensure that your code can move on although `WaitForExit` did not return. To do that I'd set a ManualResetEvent after `Kill` has completed. And instead of calling `WaitForExit`, you obtain the process handle using the `Process.Handle` property and wait on either of the two waitables to become signaled. Look at what `WaitForExit` does internally to see how you could implement this yourself (I'd copy out the `ProcessWaitHandle` class which is internal).

A simpler solution would be to call `WaitForExit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))` in a loop and check the `exited` flag each time.

Comment: I subbed my process in QtX's code above, which is simple enough. The process didn't get terminated and it was hanging at 'WaitForExit'.

Comment: So what do you think about my points why this cannot be the case? I added some code, please run it (I did). You can also try swapping the exe name for your real target, but please try both.

Comment: Reading your comments I have a new suspicion and a possible solution. I edited it in. Btw, what process are you starting? What does it do?

Comment: My process `.exe` file is a third party java based file transfer client.   "A simpler solution would be to call WaitForExit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) in a loop and check the exited flag each time."  -- this solution is simple and elegant, just what I need. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would you try a cleaner code (I think). tested.....

```
Process proc = null;

//Kill process after 3 seconds
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Task.Delay(3000).Wait();

    if(proc!=null && proc.HasExited==false) proc.Kill();
});


var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "ping.exe",
    Arguments = "-t 127.0.0.1",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};

proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = psi;
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s,e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
};

proc.Start();
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
proc.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine("**killed**");
```

Comment: did you actually try killing the 'proc' while 'proc.WaitForExit()' is still waiting? 'Console.WriteLine("**killed**");' may get executed simply because the process has finished not because you terminated it.

Comment: No, with `-t` parameter, *ping* runs infinitely. Just comment out *task* part and try.

Comment: your code worked, so I substituted the process in my code with the 'ping' process, and '.Kill();' worked. Hmmm, so there is something that doesn't allow the termination of my process. Strange.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Shouldn't this force stop a process regardless of what process it is?